# Connection from PowerDesigner to MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, connection-string, sybase, powerdesigner

I'm trying to connect from Sybase PowerDesigner 15 to MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2. I basically entered the following into the `Connection Profile Definition` dialog:

- Connection Type: Native
- DBMS Type: Microsoft SQL Server
- Server Name: `MSSQLSERVER` (which is the instance name installed on my machine, I also tried `192.168.1.44\MSSQLSERVER` which is my IP on the network and the instance name)
- Database name: `Prevent-01222013`
- Use integrated login: checked

Unfortunately, it keeps telling me "Connection Failed!". Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the `Server Name` (in `Connection Profile Definition`) uses an `Alias` defined through the `SQL Server Configuration Manager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok apparently I was doing it all wrong. I ended up using the `ODBC machine data source` option and that did it.